# Sum up minima of data pairs in a matrix

Tags: r

I would like to compare the elements of two rows in a matrix and then sum up the minima of the data pairs.

For example in a matrix like this the result should be 3 (1+1+1+0)

```
> m
  col1 col2 col3 col4
a    2    1    4    4
b    1    2    1    0
```

I tried it like this:

```
> findmin <- function (x) for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {min(x[1,i], x[2,i])}
> res <- sum(findmin(m))
> res
[1] 0
```

I think the problem is that the loop returns NULL as a value. How can i avoid this? Or is there a more elegant way to do it avoiding the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

`apply()` is your friend:

```
R> M <- matrix(c(2,1,4,4,1,2,1,0), 2, 4, byrow=TRUE)
R> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    4    4
[2,]    1    2    1    0
R> apply(M, 1, min)                       # goes row-wise
[1] 1 0
R> apply(M, 2, min)                       # goes column-wise
[1] 1 1 1 0
R> sum(apply(M, 2, min))
[1] 3
R>
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum(apply(m, 2, min))` does the trick:

```
> m <- matrix(c(2,1,4,4,1,2,1,0), 2, byrow=TRUE)

> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    4    4
[2,]    1    2    1    0

> sum(apply(m, 2, min))
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "R" way to solve this task would be with an apply function: `sum(apply(m, 2, min))`

Your for loop didn't work because you weren't storing or returning any value. Here's how to fix your for loop. Note that preallocating the size of `out` makes it execute much faster:

```
findmin <- function(x){
    out <- rep(NA, ncol(x))
    for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
        out[i] <- min(x[1,i], x[2,i])
    }
    return(out)
}
> findmin(m)
[1] 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I had been trying to figure out how to return values from loops in R for a while.